# mysql tagging system that allows multiple and duplicate tags

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm building a MySQL tagging DB to allow users to tag products.

My current design uses these tables:

```
Account
id (PK)
username

Product
id (PK)
product_name

Product_Tag
id (PK)
product_id (FK to Product)
tag_id (FK to Tag)
account_id (FK to Account)
created_date

Tag
id (PK)
tag_name
```

Note in my design, I'm tracking which user tagged the product and when, and enabling a product to be tagged multiple times using the same tag so I know which tags are most popular for a given product.

I'm trying to figure out a tag search query that returns products most tagged to the searched tags.  For example, if I query "red dress", products that are more heavily tagged with "red" and "dress" should appear towards the top in the result set. What query can accomplish this with my existing design?

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(cnt) from(
    select count(*) cnt
    from product_tag
    where tag_id = <tag id of red dress>
    group by product_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is most like a `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.ProductName
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN Product_Tag b
            ON a.ID = b.Product_ID
        INNER JOIN Tag c
            ON b.Tag_ID = c.ID
WHERE   a.ProductName IN ('RED','ADDRESS')
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.ProductName
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER   BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    P.id,
    P.product_name
FROM Product P
    LEFT JOIN Product_tag PT
        ON P.id = PT.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Tag T
        On PT.tag_id = T.id
WHERE T.tag_name = 'red'
     OR T.tag_name = 'dress'
GROUP BY P.id, P.product_name
ORDER BY COUNT(P.id) DESC
```

you cant use `LIMIT` to to get first `n` most tagged products.